# How do I parse this nested JSON using Codable with Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I am trying to parse this JSON using Codable:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Allen Carslake",
      "userName": "acarslake0",
      "profileImage": "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400",
      "createdDate": "2019-07-08T00:00:00.000+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Revkah Antuk",
      "userName": "rantuk1",
      "profileImage": "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400",
      "createdDate": "2019-07-05T00:00:00.000+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Mirna Saffrin",
      "userName": "msaffrin2",
      "profileImage": "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400",
      "createdDate": "2019-05-19T00:00:00.000+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Haily Eilers",
      "userName": "heilers3",
      "profileImage": "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400",
      "createdDate": "2019-06-28T00:00:00.000+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Oralie Polkinhorn",
      "userName": "opolkinhorn4",
      "profileImage": "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400",
      "createdDate": "2019-06-04T00:00:00.000+0000"
    }
]
}
```

I am keeping the URL private on here but it is returning JSON above. So far this is my code:

```
import UIKit

struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let userName: String
    let profileImage: String
    let createdDate: String
}

struct Users: Codable {
    let users: String
}

let url = URL(string: "")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

    if let data = data {

        let users = try? JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
        print(users)
    }

    }.resume()
```

I need to be able to access the User properties but I think the nesting is making it difficult for me. Any help is awesome!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

First of all: **`Catch` always the `DecodingError` and `print` it. It tells you exactly what's wrong**.

The error occurs because you are ignoring the root object `Users`. Your code works if you `decode(Users.self`.

My suggestions:

- Decode `createdDate` as `Date` adding a appropriate date decoding strategy.
- Decode `profileImage` as `URL` (for free).
- Handle **all** errors.

---

```
struct Root : Decodable { // `Users` and `User` is too confusing
    let users: [User]
}

struct User : Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let userName: String
    let profileImage: URL
    let createdDate: Date
}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in

    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
        let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data!)
        for user in result.users {
           print(user.userName, user.id, user.createdDate)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

The root of the json is a dictionary not an array you can write a root class but it will be useless  , so you need

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

   do {     
    if let data = data { 
        let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
        let usersData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: res["users"])
        let users = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: usersData) 
        print(users)
    }
   }
   catch {
     print(error)
   }

}.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Users` struct (I renamed it to `UsersResponse`) should contain a `users` property of type `[User]`. Then you can do the following:

```
struct UsersResponse: Codable {
    let users: [User]
}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
    guard let data = data else { return }

    if let users = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Users.self, from: data).users {
        users.forEach { user in
            print("A user called \(user.name) with an id of \(user.id).")
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: writing `UsersResponse`   will have a meaning if there are more properties to access , but since it's only `users` key then no need for it

Comment: Nevertheless I prefer this solution over your `JSONSerialization` one, @Sh_Khan. :)

Comment: Worked, thank you! Now how can I access the User properties such as "id" and "profileImage"?

Comment: @ReissZurbyk If you ask a question like that then you need to learn about arrays and using loops, may I suggest [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html), it's an excellent resource when learning swift and even later on

Comment: @JoakimDanielson. I have added error handling my answer please check.

Comment: @Animesh I didn't comment on your answer (yet)

Comment: Do you ask me or do you ask the author, @JoakimDanielson? The question was not about error handling but about the structure. So I took the original snippet and made some small changes... :)

Comment: Simple JSON questions like this are asked almost daily by beginners so I think we should expect the answer to be of good quality and show the use of some good coding habits since they are directed to beginners.

Comment: Feel free to provide an answer that lives up to your expectations, @JoakimDanielson :)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! I'm still trying to print the properties like "userName" and "createdDate" and then I think I've got it! Can someone show me how I can access those nested values?

Comment: Updated my answer, @ReissZurbyk. Except of that I also think you should check some more general Swift resources like Joakim already stated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. This is working for me.

**Model Class:**

```
struct UsersResponse: Codable {
   let users: [User]
}

struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let userName: String
    let profileImage: String?
    let createdDate: String
}
```

**Network class:**

```
public enum EndPoints: String {
    case prod = "ProdURL"
    case test = "testURL"
}

public enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}

final public class Networking: NSObject {


// MARK: - Private functions
private static func getData(url: URL,
                            completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completion).resume()
}

/// fetchUsersResponse function will fetch the User Response and returns
/// Result<UsersResponse> as completion handler

 public static func fetchUsersResponse(shouldFail: Bool = false, completion: @escaping (Result<UsersResponse>) -> Void) {
    var urlString: String?
    if shouldFail {
        urlString = EndPoints.test.rawValue
    } else {
        urlString = EndPoints.prod.rawValue
    }

    guard let mainUrlString = urlString,  let url = URL(string: mainUrlString) else { return }

    Networking.getData(url: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }

        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            //decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(setDateFormat())

            let json = try decoder.decode(UsersResponse.self, from: data)
            completion(.success(json))
        } catch let error {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}

func setDateFormat() -> DateFormatter {
    let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    return dateFormat
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks a little over the top but there are two things I wonder about, firstly why did you make every property optional in the struct, only make them optional if you know they are and secondly what the heck is `decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970`?

Comment: Thanks for informing, @JoakimDanielson, I have used one of my template code. So in the above JSON structure, there is no date format so I can remove **dateDecodingStrategy**.
For optional properties in the struct, I used to follow this practice to make code behavior safe in case of null/nil value comes from the server or any key missing from server response then it wont break.

Comment: If a mandatory key is missing then it should break, otherwise you might get unpredicted behaviour later on. We all have our own preferences and I think it is a bad habit to make everything optional.

Comment: @Animesh Actually there **is** a date format, but it's not `.millisecondsSince1970`. And regarding safety there is no difference at all between an optional and a caught `DecodingError`. In both cases the decoding process fails but in the non-optional scenario you get a comprehensive error message and you can fix the code at once.

Comment: Thanks, @vadian for inputs. Could you please tell me what should I use in place of .millisecondsSince1970

Comment: @Animesh Use`.formatted` with a `DateFormatter` and date format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: @vadian...Cool Sir. Thanks for the suggestion of good practice.

Comment: Take the DateFormatter out of the function.

Comment: Np, I would make it a lazy variable. Since you only want to make it once and since dateformatters are expensive when initializing. Other than that looks good